# Is it possible to use the STL multimap value_type function with a multiple argument C++ constructor

Tags: c++, linux, stl

Good morning , In Scott Meyers book Effective STL, Mr Meyers explains how the map::value_type function saves the cost of construction and deletion of a temporary object. 
    We are trying use Mr. Meyers technique with a multimap where the class Range has two constructors:

```
class Range { 
     public:   
         explicit Range(int item){ 
                .....
         }
         Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0,char* mapptr = 0, int stamp = 0, 
               int casenumber = 100, int currN = 0){  
            .......     
         }
};
```

The Linux g++ compiler complains when we try the following code:

```
void cMemoryMappedFile::AddFinalRange(int CurrN)
{
    typedef std::multiset<Range> RangeMultiSet;
    typedef std::multimap<char*, Range> RangeMultiMap;
    // OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
    ranges_type.insert(RangeMultiSet::value_type(PreviousN,FileSize,
        &prevadjustedptr[PreviousN],MapPtr,TimeStamp + 1,0,CurrN));

    // OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
    mmultimap.insert(std::make_pair(MapPtr,
        Range(PreviousN,FileSize,&prevadjustedptr[PreviousN],
        MapPtr,TimeStamp +  1,0,CurrN)));


    // Not OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
    mmultimap.insert(RangeMultiMap::value_type((char* const)MapPtr,
        PreviousN,FileSize,&prevadjustedptr[PreviousN],
        MapPtr,TimeStamp + 1,0,CurrN));
}
```

The G++ 4.1.2 compiler error is this:

```
g++ -g -Wall -W -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -D_DEBUG -pthread -DTHREADSAFE -m32 
-D_NO_GUI -DDTAPI -DNO_LOOKUP_DBF -DNO_ASCII -DCONFIG_SECURITY  
-I../Include -I../../cpswindows/Include -I../../sqlite 
-I../../util -I../../zlib -I../../str 
-I/home/frankc/DQTTest2/valgrind-3.6.1/callgrind -I/home/frankc/DQTTest2/valgrind-3.6.1/include 
-fpic ../Source/cMemoryMappedFile.cpp -o cMemoryMappedFile.o -c
../Source/cMemoryMappedFile.cpp: In member function ‘void cMemoryMappedFile::AddFinalRange(int)’:
../Source/cMemoryMappedFile.cpp:663: 
error: no matching function for call to 
std::pair<char* const, Range>::pair(char* const, unsigned int&, long int&, char*, char*&, 
int, int, int&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h:84: 
note: candidates are: std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) 
[with _T1 = char* const, _T2 = Range]
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h:80: note: 
                std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair() [with _T1 = char* const, _T2 = Range]
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_pair.h:69: note: 
                std::pair<char* const, Range>::pair(const std::pair<char* const, Range>&)
```

We were wondering if it possible to fix this compiler error so that we can we can use the multimap::value_type function so we can use Mr. Meyers technique? Thank you.

Comment: Format your question, please (:

Comment: Here is our typedef:   typedef std::multiset<Range> RangeMultiSet;
                typedef std::multimap<char*, Range> RangeMultiMap; Thank you.

Comment: @Kirol Kirov, Please explain how  I format my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, I did it(formatting) for you. Please, do not break it :)

Comment: `value_type` is a data member which is simply a typedef of the `pair<const Key,T>`. It's not a function. Also see here on how to do an insert into multimap: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/insert/

Comment: @yasouer, Thank you for reply. We look at your multimap insert link and we are currently using mmultimap.insert(std::make_pair(MapPtr,Range). If we use the code in your link, multimap.insert(pair(MapPtr,Range) would we save the cost of constructing and deleting a temporary Range object. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Steve Jessop, Thank you for your comment. Could you explain to us why our  typedef std::multimap<char*, Range> RangeMultiMap is being rejected by the g++ 4.1.2 compiler when we try mmultimap::insert(RangeMultiMap::value_type(...)? Is it possible for us to fix this compiler error so we follw the Scott Meyers Effective STL technique? Thnak you.

Comment: Are you sure the temporary is actually constructed, copied and destructed? The compiler is allowed to elide copying temporaries and quite often will.

Comment: @Alan Stokes, we looked at callgrind/Kcachegrind profile output for our program and we obsevred many thousands of Range constructor calls and Range destructor calls. Could you please suggest a way we can tell if a temporary Range is actually constructed and deleted? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Look at the generated object code (eg in gdb). Also - how many of the constructor calls you saw were copy constructors? You can't avoid constructing them, but you may be able to avoid copying them.

Comment: @Alan Stokes, Thank you for your reply, We will try to look at the generated object code in gdb. Could you please tell us how to recognize if the object code is using a Range copy constructor? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option would be available as `emplace` in a compiler supporting C++0x, like gcc 4.5 or 4.6.

Currently std::pair can only be constructed with two parameters. Variadic templates will change that and offer new possibilities, as will rvalue references and perfect forwarding.

Comment: @Bo Persson, Thank you for your answer. If I understand your answer correctly, we would have to use the STL map emplace member function in a complier supporting C++0x such as gcc 4.5. Is there are any workaround so that with g++ 4.1.2 we can save the cost of constructing and deleting a temporary Range object with STL mmultimap::insert? Thank you for your help,

Comment: @Frank - Right now (C++03) you will have to construct the value and copy it into the multimap. Possibly the optimizer can improve some of it. The `emplace` will let you construct in place when that is important, either as a speed optimization or because the object just isn't copyable.

Comment: @Bo Persson, Thank you for your reply. Could you please tell us if there any g++ compiler flags we can use so that the optimizer can improve the temporary object handling? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank - No, there are no specific flags for this, just that higher optimization levels will likely increase the odds.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's simplify this a bit would you :p ?

```
// OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
mmultimap.insert(std::make_pair(MapPtr,
    Range(PreviousN,FileSize,&prevadjustedptr[PreviousN],
    MapPtr,TimeStamp +  1,0,CurrN)));


// Not OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
mmultimap.insert(RangeMultiMap::value_type((char* const)MapPtr,
    PreviousN,FileSize,&prevadjustedptr[PreviousN],
    MapPtr,TimeStamp + 1,0,CurrN));
```

Is in fact similar to:

```
// OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
mmultimap.insert(std::make_pair(MapPtr, Range(0)));


// Not OK with g++ 4.1.2 Compiler
mmultimap.insert(RangeMultiMap::value_type(MapPtr, 0));
```

Note:

- the cast is completely unnecessary
- the constructor of `Range` is `explicit`, and thus won't be called

The issue here is that `value_type` expect both a `Key` and `Value`, but you provide a `Key` and some garbage.

You have to call the constructor of `Range`, and *hope* for Copy Elision to kick in. It is likely that it will.

Comment: Elison, Thank you for your answer, If we follow your suggestion mmultimap.insert(RangeMultiMap::value_type(MapPtr,Range(PreviousN, FileSize,&prevadjustedptr[PreviousN],MapPtr,TimeStamp + 1, CurrentN)) are you suggesting that Copy Elision will save the cost of temporary object deletion? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Yes, it should build the `Range` object directly "in place" within the `value_type` object. Note that `emplace` would still perform better, but it's only available in C++0x.